# Help with xinttools

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, mathematics, xint

`xinttools` package allows to plot function summation. Given a function `f(x,n)`, these curves

```
f(x,1)
f(x,1) + f(x,2)
f(x,1) + f(x,2) + f(x,3)
```

will be plotted using

```
 \def\myterm#1{#1*x + 7}
 ...
 \xintFor #1 in {1,2,3} \do 
    {%    
    \addplot+[samples=300,smooth] 
     {\xintListWithSep{+}{\xintApply\myterm{\xintSeq{0}{#1}}}}; 
    }
```

Is there a way to draw **only the last curve**, ie

```
f(x,1) + f(x,2) + f(x,3)
```

Also, I would like to know if it is possible to declare the range as in ordinary foreach, in the form

```
{1,2,...,n}
```

Comment: Well, programmatically you want to run the loop first without the `\addplot`, and only add the plot after the loop. It would help if you can include a compileable example that we can just copy and paste, so we don't have to try to recreate your source code from scratch.

Comment: why the loop? why not directly `\addplot+[samples=300,smooth] 
     {\xintListWithSep{+}{\xintApply\myterm{\xintSeq{0}{3}}}};` ? And as @WillieWong said please include some small example we can play with.  Notice that actually f(x,0)+f(x,1)+f(x,2)+f(x,3) is plotted.  If you don't want f(x,0) you should use \xintSeq{1}{3} or here in this case simply {1}{2}{3} according to xinttools documentation.  About your last question I suspect TikZ/pgfplots make using xinttools unneeded.

Comment: Did your code come from some other answer on this site? if yes maybe link to it.

Comment: @user691586 if the question about the loop is directed at me: that is because I am not familiar with the `xinttools` macros and assumed (incorrectly) that OP's loop is keeping track of a running total and plotting the resulting sum each time.

Comment: @WillieWong my question was directed to OP... the loop of OP simply creates successive plots (each time with one more added term) but does not keep track of a running total; the "total" is recrated from scratch each time by the `\xintListWithSep{+}` stuff which appears to construct an infix expression with `+` as separators as I tested in an `\edef`.